# Mysql Java connector detect wrong timezone from server

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I got a very strange problem.

My local timezone is `UTC+8`. I think server's timezone is also `UTC+8` according to the following command:

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
+--------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP) |
+--------------------------------+
| 08:00:00                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But Java's driver detect the server's timezone is `UTC-5`. More specifically, assuming that my local time is `13:00`, if I insert a `new Date()` into the database, then the actual time I inserted is `00:00`.

However, if I append `serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai`(which is UTF+8) to mysql's url, everything goes well.

Detail server's informations list below:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- Contents in `/etc/timezone` is `Asia/Shanghai`
- Mysql Server version: 5.6.31-0ubuntu0.14.04.2-log (Ubuntu)
- `spring.datasource.driver-class-name`=`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`
- Driver version: `mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.5`

I've confused with this problem for long time, could anyone give me an answer?